# Configure postfix to accept mail from external MX

Tags: postfix, mx-record

I'm trying to switch my postfix configuration from accepting mail directly, to pointing my MX record to a different host and then only accepting mail coming in from that MX host.  So far, that's only resulted in mail being rejected.

Steps taken:

1. Change MX record to point to external mail forwarding host
2. Add ip addresses for mail forwarding host to my_networks
3. Set smtp_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject

Comment: What else in `main.cf`? What's the reason it gives for the reject?

Answer (score 0):

Update: The settings I described do actually work.  The reasons for the initial failure are unclear.